# Is there a way to deserialize an object into "$this"?

Tags: php, oop, memcached

I'm writing a class to handle a memcached object. The idea was to create `abstract class Cachable` and all the cachable objects (such as User, Post, etc) would be subclasses of said class.

The class offers some method such as `Load()` which calls the abstract function `LoadFromDB()` if the object is not cached, functions to refresh/invalidate the cache, etc.

The main problem is in `Load()`; I wanted to do something similar:

```
protected function Load($id)
{
    $this->memcacheId = $id;
    $this->Connect();

    $cached = $this->memcache->get(get_class($this) . ':' . $id);

    if($cached === false)
    {
        $this->SetLoaded(LoadFromDB($id));
        UpdateCache();
    } else {
        $this = $cached;
        $this->SetLoaded(true);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I need `$this` to become `$cached` (the cached object); is there any way to do that? Was the "every cachable object derives from the cachable class" a bad design idea?

Comment: Shouldn't "Cachable" be an interface rather than an abstract class? And why couldn't you use the `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` magic functions, or implement the `Serializable` interface?

Comment: @Byron: it couldn't because interfaces cannot implement functions. I don't understand how __sleep/__wakeup can help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about copying the properties from $cached to $this instead?

```
foreach (get_object_vars($cached) as $field => $value) {
  $this->$field = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to deserialize an object into “$this”?

As far as I am aware (and from reading the answers to date), the answer is no.

However it'd be fairly trivial to write a decorator object which would wrap around just about anything....

```
 class mydecorator {
    var $mydec_real_obj;
    function deserialize($inp)
    {
       $this->mydec_real_obj=unserialize($inp);
    }
    function __set($name, $val) 
    {
        $this->mydec_real_obj->$name=$val;
    }
    function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array( 
             array(0=>$this->mydec_real_obj, 1=>$method),
             $args);
    }

 // ... etc
```

C.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make it a static method (Note, for 5.3+ only, since otherwise there's no way to tell the calling class due to late static binding issues)...

```
protected static function Load($id) {
    $memcache = Memcache::getInstance();
    $cached = $memcache->get(get_called_class() . ':' . $id);
    if($cached === false) {
        $ret = new static();
        $ret->SetLoaded(LoadFromDB($id));
        UpdateCache();
    } else {
        $ret = $cached;
        $ret->SetLoaded(true);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
$user = User::load(4);
$user->foo;
```